# Why does switching to protected restarts the machine?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, qemu, protected-mode

I'm trying to create very simple operating system in 64 bits. I'm trying to enter protected mode first, but I'm failing at this point.

When I do the far jump into 32 bits, the machine restarts.

My code is loaded into memory with another assembly program at the address 0x100.

The code is compiled with nasm and I'm running the program using `qemu -fda`.

Here is the code I got so far:

```
[BITS 16]

jmp _start

_start:
    cli

    lgdt [GDT64]

    ; Switch to protected mode
    mov eax, cr0
    or al, 1b
    mov cr0, eax

    ; Desactivate pagination
    mov eax, cr0
    and eax, 01111111111111111111111111111111b
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp (CODE_SELECTOR-GDT64):pm_start

[BITS 32]

pm_start:
    jmp $

GDT64:
    NULL_SELECTOR:
        dw GDT_LENGTH   ; limit of GDT
        dw GDT64        ; linear address of GDT
        dd 0x0

    CODE_SELECTOR:          ; 32-bit code selector (ring 0)
        dw 0x0FFFF
        db 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
        db 10011010b
        db 11001111b
        db 0x0

    DATA_SELECTOR:          ; flat data selector (ring 0)
        dw  0x0FFFF
        db  0x0, 0x0, 0x0
        db  10010010b
        db  10001111b
        db  0x0

    LONG_SELECTOR:  ; 64-bit code selector (ring 0)
        dw  0x0FFFF
        db  0x0, 0x0, 0x0
        db  10011010b       ;
        db  10101111b
        db  0x0

   GDT_LENGTH:
```

If I do a `jmp $` before the long jump, it works, the program is halted correctly, but when the long jump is done, it reboots the machine.

Did I forgot to setup something like a segment or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your comment says, you need the linear address of GDT. You don't seem to have specified any `ORG` directive, so the assembler will use a base address of 0, and that won't match the address at runtime.

Also, not sure how you load the code at `0x100`, the boot sector is normally loaded at `0x7c00`.

The solution could be as simple as specifying `ORG 0x7c00` at the top of your file.

Comment: God, I already tried but I had forgotten to reset the segment registers, now, it works well. Thanks.